# Creating a number of sets based on amount of command line arguments

Tags: python

My program is going to be comparing an arbitrary amount of sets.
If the amount is determined by amount of command line arguments, how can I make a unique set for each argument?

Comment: make a `list` of sets.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast
import sys

def main(sets):
    # now do something with them

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sets = [
        set(ast.literal_eval(arg))
        for arg in sys.argv[1:]
    ]
    main(sets)
```

which you can call like

```
python myprog.py "1, 2" "1, 5" "6, 7, 8" "12, 13"
```

and results in calling

```
main([{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {8, 6, 7}, {12, 13}])
```